# How to restrict how far a slider can be adjusted in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, slider, swiftui

If you have a slider in SwiftUI, with a set range, how can I make it so you can't go past a certain value (even if it was in the range). I know it sounds counterintuitive, but what I'm trying to do is make a slider that shows the current time, and I don't want someone to be able to adjust the time before the current time, if that makes sense.

Comment: Would you provide your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do something like this, the key is to use the Binding setup:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

@State var timeSelection = 0.0
@State var currentTime = 20.0  // <-- whatever value

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Slider(value: Binding(
            get: { self.timeSelection },
            set: {
                if $0 >= self.currentTime {
                    self.timeSelection = $0
                }
        }), in: 0.0...100.0, step: 1)
        Text("\(timeSelection)")
    }.onAppear(perform: {self.timeSelection = self.currentTime})
}
}
```